# Aggregating nested children ids by parentId in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, parent-child, hierarchical-data, children

There is parent-child structure like this:

[folder-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jICJ9.png)

The collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "document1",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "folder1",
    "parentId": null,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "folder2",
    "parentId": "2",
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "4"
    "name": "document2",
    "parentId": "2",
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "5"
    "name": "document3",
    "parentId": "3",
    
  }
]
```

The goal is to get folders with `contentIds` array in every folder, containing only direct children ids. The response should look like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "folder1",
    "parentId": null,
    "contentIds": ["3", "4"]
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "folder2",
    "parentId": "2",
    "contentIds": ["5"]
    
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform a self lookup and a `$map` to get your desired format of data.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RQ11AoZ7WLd) for your reference.